# diagram setup/storage/display strategies in confluence?

Tags: confluence

I need to store project diagrams in Confluence. Imagine that there's a "user flow diagram" and a "billing flow diagram."  The svg file format provides good interoperability among different diagram software tools.  But unfortunately, looks like a lot of pixelation is introduced into a diagram when converting it from an svg into a png.  So adding an svg into a Confluence page will present a low-quality pixelated view of that diagram as a preview.

I've found that I can export an svg as pdf which converts perfectly, and then convert the pdf to a png which converts at 80%+ acceptable quality.  Inserting the pdf directly into the Confluence page only displays a large thumbnail image view as opposed to an image that I can resize to fill the page.  So I need to use a png file for image preview on the page.

I worked at a previous company where we drag/dropped draw.io files onto a Confluence page which allowed the page to display a preview of the diagram in that file.  This approach also provided the ability to add a url to that diagram in the page below the diagram, as a clear way to reference the source file of that diagram for subsequent updates.  Because dragging the draw.io file onto the page made it referenceable as subsequent source url in Confluence.

So my issue now is that I'm including a png as the primary image for the diagram in the Confluence page.  But I also need a way to store the svg source file in Confluence so subsequent developers have the ability to edit/update the source diagram.  I need to figure out an efficient and elegant way to do this.  Looking for others' perspectives on how they have managed this type of setup in the past.  Any recs?